# How to extend an existing type using graphql-js classes (no SDL)?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Using SDL, I can do this:

```
extend type Query {
   something: String!
}
```

How can I do that when building a type via the built-in `GraphQLObjectType` class?

It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

[This library](https://graphql-compose.github.io/docs/intro/quick-start.html) might help?

having done

```
const AuthorTC = TypeComposer.create({
  name: 'Author',
  fields: {
    id: 'Int!',
    firstName: 'String',
    lastName: 'String',
  },
});
```

you can then do `addFields`

```
AuthorTC.addFields({ ... })
```

and get the `GraphQLObjectType`

```
AuthorTC.getType()
```